# Save WP login form data to a .txt document on form submission

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, authentication

I'm looking for a snippet that enables me to get the data from a WordPress login form added to a .txt document every time a user logs in from the /wp-login.php page. Once the .txt document is created, the code/snippet should 'capture' the username/email and password submitted through the /wp-login.php form every time a user logs in. I hope it makes sense so far. So for example, once this snippet is added somewhere on the website, I go to the /wp-login.php page, log in, and the snippet captures my username/email and password and adds them to the .txt document. And it does this every time someone logs in, updating the same .txt document.

I know it's not possible to do this with a form action since there's already an action for the `loginform` (which is `action="<?php echo esc_url( site_url( 'wp-login.php', 'login_post' ) ); ?>"`), and you can't have two actions for the same form.

Any ideas how this might be achieved?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: you want to hack ? there is a lot of plugin that logs all the login and other actions and all the user are already stored in the DB, so why you need this

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code in your functions.php file of your theme.

```
function after_login_function( $user_login, $user ) {
    // your code to write to a file
}
add_action('wp_login', 'after_login_function', 10, 2);
```

The first function parameter $user_login is the user login name and the second is the WP_USER object you can access all types of information about the user.

Comment: thanks for the input! However, I'm not good at PHP so I wouldn't be able to write the code needed to write to a .txt file. I was hoping somebody could help me with that, at least to a point. That is, if there's no snippet already available for this kind of thing. Best!

Comment: I agree with the other user's comments.  There's already plugins that will do that will store login attempts but storing passwords in plain text is a very bad idea.